# What does 'in 10 minutes' mean?

Tags: meaning

We'll be landing in 10 minutes.

Are they landing within 10 minutes or after 10 minutes?

Comment: It means that the time the plane touches the ground will be approximately 10 minutes from now.

Comment: @PeterShor *Approximately* can fall on either side, *within* cannot.

Comment: @Kris: *Approximately* is what I meant.  If somebody says *"We'll be landing **in** ten minutes,"* it could be nine minutes or eleven minutes. If somebody says *"We'll be landing **within** ten minutes,"* the landing should be ten minutes or less away. If somebody says *"We'll be landing **after** ten minutes,"* the landing should be ten minutes or more away.

Comment: @PeterShor You are correct in that that's what people usually mean to say, though we will be wrong in defining it differently from what the language actually implies per semantics or even pragmatics. Hope you see the point.

Comment: @Kris: I don't see the point. Why should *in* mean the same as *within* here? It certainly doesn't always.

Comment: @Kris I have to agree with Peter Shor.  _In 10 minutes_ is an approximation, _within_ or _in under_ would mean _in less than_.  I think I understand your thought, that _in_ implies _inside_, but in this use, I do not think this applies.  Do you have some reference to support your interpretation here.  I'm curious if others hold the same interpretation.

Comment: Peter is correct in stressing that the pragmatics has to inform the semantics here. 99.99+% of people saying "We'll be landing in 10 minutes" aren't claiming an accuracy of plus or minus a nanosecond, and mean something like 'more than 8 but less than 12'.

Answer (score 3):

It means that there are still 10 more minutes before the aircraft touches ground.

Answer (score -1):

Means that when 10 minutes have passed , the plane will have landed. 
It is the maximum length of time that the expected event is due to take.

Comment: actually you're right, I misread the question.

Answer (score -3):

It means the landing will take place in under ten minutes.

Probably between five and ten minutes to landing....If it had been less than five minutes they would have said "we'll be landing in five minutes".

Comment: Why the down votes?

Comment: @Kris: Because the answer is wrong. The preposition *in* does not mean the same thing as *within* here. That is, the preposition *in* means *"ten minutes from now"*, not *"ten minutes from now or sooner"*. If you tell somebody: *"I want you to push this button in ten minutes"*, and they push it right away, they have disobeyed your instructions. If you had said *"within ten minutes"*, they would have obeyed them.